# C# --- Merging two lists and taking the duplicates into a new list then printing that list

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

```
    {
        public static List<string> DuplicateNames(List<Person> a, List<Person> b)
        {
            List<string> DuplicatePeople = a.Intersect(b).ToList();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> personsA = new List<Person>();
            personsA.Add(new Person("Emma"));
            personsA.Add(new Person("Eva"));
            personsA.Add(new Person("Data"));
            List<Person> personsB = new List<Person>();
            personsB.Add(new Person("Anna"));
            personsB.Add(new Person("Eva"));
            personsB.Add(new Person("Emma"));

            List<string> myDuplicateNames = Program.DuplicateNames(personsA, personsB);

            foreach (String s in myDuplicateNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
           }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

```
    class Person
    {
        private string name;

        public Person(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }

    }
```

As the title says, I'm trying to combine list personA and personB into a new list with a funtion "DuplicateNames". I then want to call the funtion and that takes the duplicate names in the new list into "myDuplicatenNames" and printing that list.

I'm pretty new to C# and can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st problem: a is a list of person and you try to assign it to a list of strings.
2nd problem: 2 persons with the same name are not equal. You can override Equals, but LINQ offers you a more flexible way.

```cs
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; }   // Read-only default property, initialized in constructor.

        public Person(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static List<string> DuplicateNames(List<Person> a, List<Person> b)
        {
            // LINQ 1:
            List<string> duplicatePeople = a
                .Select(a => a.Name)                              // Projecting a list of persons to a list of strings
                .Where(a => b.Select(p => p.Name).Contains(a))   // Check for each item if it's in the list of names of b.
                .ToList();  

            // LINQ 2: Join
            var duplicatePeople2 = a.Join(
                    b,                                    // 2nd List
                    a => a.Name,                          // What ist the key of the first list?
                    b => b.Name,                          // What ist the key of the second list?
                    (a, b) => a)                          // Secting the item of the first list (if you have more properties in class Person, this could be different from the item of the second list)
                .Select(p => p.Name)                      // Again: projecting to a list of strings
                .ToList();
            return duplicatePeople;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // List offers an initializer.
            var personsA = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person("Emma"),
                new Person("Eva"),
                new Person("Data")
            };

            var personsB = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person("Anna"),
                new Person("Eva"),
                new Person("Emma")
            };

            List<string> myDuplicateNames = DuplicateNames(personsA, personsB);

            foreach (var s in myDuplicateNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answers seems to work for me. It was way more complicated than I made it out to be in my head. I'll make sure to study and learn what you supplied. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be modified to work with `Intersect` method you currently use. The problem is that in your implementation you try to compare class that you created: `Person`. By default comparison happens by reference and not by the content of the properties. In order for it to work, you could override `Equals` on your `Person` class:

```cs
class Person
{
    private string name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Person person &&
                name == person.name &&
                Name == person.Name;
    }            
}
```

One more note on your `DuplicateNames` method, it should be modified do what you want it to do, transform list of duplicate `Person`s to list of duplicate `string`s using `Select` method:

```cs
public static List<string> DuplicateNames(List<Person> a, List<Person> b)
{
    return a.Intersect(b).Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll take the answer and study it.